# Cannot upload a MP4 file to Plone 3.1.1

Tags: file, video, upload, plone, mp4

I have an MP4 file that I have been trying to upload for four days. It is a 48 minute long video of a webinar training conducted, so I need to put it on Plone so that it can be accessed by staff. When I try to upload it, a small box in the lower corner shows Updating X%, but it keeps running from 0 to 100% over and over again. I left it running overnight and it still never uploaded. It's stuck in some type of loop. I am able to upload other files, including other MP4 files. I originally thought it was the video, so I reproduced it in my video editing software. Same results. It does not matter how I save the video (different resolutions, different fps, different bitrates, different extensions), this video will not upload. I have tried from my office, a co-worker's office, and my home to see if it was a network issue. I have used different user accounts and had others try to upload it. We have used multiple browsers. I cannot find an error messages to tell em what is going on. We even rebooted the server. Has anyone else ran into this? Is there a hidden place for error messages? I am frustrated with this.
If additional information is needed, please contact me. Due to confidentiality, I cannot provide the video itself.

Comment: A couple of questions to help us answer the question:  What add-on are you using to facilitate file uploads (if any)? Are you able to upload smaller video files? Do you know of any file-size limits that might be set either in your HTTP proxy (apache or nginx) or in Zope itself?  For examples of such, see [this mailing-list post](http://plone.293351.n2.nabble.com/File-upload-limit-td6183905.html) or [this blog post](http://keeshink.blogspot.com/2009/09/how-to-limit-file-upload-size.html)

Comment: I just took over the management of this site this week, so I have more to learn (much more). I can upload other files larger and smaller than this one. As far as the other questions, I hate to say that I can't answer those. I have poked around in the Zope management interface for the information in the links you provided without finding anything mentioning file size. On the site set up page, I do see where is says "Add on Product Configuration" but the only two things listed as Analytics for Plone and Workflow Policies. Neither of them say anything about uploading files.

Comment: What is the size of your file in bytes?  Check that this does not exceed the maximum upload size you have configured in Plone.

Comment: It is 787MB. But I don't know what the size limit is on Plone. I cannot find it anywhere, even using the links that were provided in a previous response.

Comment: The browser bouncing back and forth between 0 and 100% indicates that there is some kind of client software at work doing the uploading. It may -- or may not -- be working in conjunction with a Plone add-on. But you've got to figure out what that is before anyone can help you with this.